# Is there a way to call functions on the exact text of a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, substitution, counting, countif

I'm making a spreadsheet in Google Sheets where I analyze music genres based on specific predetermined data. Because of how I've set it up, my method of checking how many elements there are is counting the number of "+" symbols in the formula, but I am currently unable to do that.

For instance, the exact text of cell B2 is currently "=26+26+26+26+13+24+12+24+24+24+22", which equates to and displays as 247. There are 10 "+" symbols in this cell. When I call the code =LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"+","")) on this cell, the number returned is 0, as it is checking the text "247" for "+" symbols. Is there a way to call a function on the exact inputted text of a formula, instead of the value the formula returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FORMULATEXT` is what you are looking for...

try:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1), "[0-9=]", ))+1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't end up using your exact formula, but FORMULATEXT gave me exactly what I wanted.